# How to use fakeslant as slanted but not italic font with fontspec?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, italic, slanted

Using `fontspec` with Luatex it is possible to create a fake slant and use that as italic should no italics be around:

```
\setmainfont[ AutoFakeSlant=0.15 ]
            {FontName}
```

However, also if an italic version exist this faked slant will be used both for `\itshape` and `\slshape`. How can I keep using the shipped italic font defined by the `ItalicFont=` parameter to `\setmainfont` but use fake slant for `\slshape`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An example is Linux Libertine, that has no slanted version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  SlantedFont={Linux Libertine O},
  SlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.15},
  BoldSlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.15},
]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
\textit{abc}\textsl{abc}\textbf{\textsl{abc}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On my installation (texlive2014 pre-freeze) this affects small caps, which invariably end up slanted as well.

Comment: @PavelRudnev See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228831/is-there-a-good-workaround-for-the-fact-that-when-using-fontspec-to-do-fake-slan