# Why does fake slant only seem to work after italics has been used?

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, italic

Based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128562/how-to-use-fakeslant-as-slanted-but-not-italic-font-with-fontspec), can someone explain this behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  SlantedFont={Linux Libertine O},
  SlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.30},
  BoldSlantedFeatures={FakeSlant=0.30},
  ]{Linux Libertine O}

  \begin{document}
      abc \textsl{abc} \textit{abc} \textsl{abc} \textbf{\textsl{abc}}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

It seems the fake slant only works after italics has been used. Am I doing something crazy or is this a very subtle bug?

Comment: The font used in both instances is `"LinuxLibertineO:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;slant=0.30;"`, so I guess it's a bug of `luaotfload`. The same happens if you repeat the input preceded by, say, `\large`.

Comment: Confirmed. It’s a bug in the fontloader, see this test file: https://bitbucket.org/phg/lua-la-tex-tests/src/3f211b03dbe97bbbc2a0d0be259a9b35ead14546/pln-slant-2.tex

Comment: After some testing it appears to be an instance of a known bug in the backend: see http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=829 and  https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/81 . You’ll have to wait for the Luatex people to fix it.

Comment: And there isn't really any workarounds because once the slant has actually been turned on it runs for the entire line, right?

Comment: Update: this bug is fixed in the latest Luatex, version 0.78.

Comment: I just updated to latest texlive and that did not help :(
What is ETA for such a patch reaching a repo near me? :)

Comment: @jonalv At the moment you have to compile from source, which is pretty simple, though: 1) get the trunk from SVN https://foundry.supelec.fr/scm/?group_id=10 , 2) copy the file ``texmf.cnf`` from your tex live install to the ``source/texk/kpathsea`` directory, 3) in the luatex-trunk directory execute ``build.sh --parallel``, 4) copy the binary from build/texk/web2c/luatex to the texlive bin directory, 5) remake the formats ``mktexfmt luatex`` etc., 6) profit.
If you don’t have a compiler I’m afraid you are going to have to wait until somebody builds 0.78 for tex live.

Comment: @phg Maybe you should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is fixed in the latest update of texlive